# Data outputted three times after every 2 seconds isn't being printed line by line on ttk.treeview chart-only printed in one burst after the third time

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-3.9, issue-tracking

Here's a simplified version of what I have currently:

```
def run(): 
        i = 1
        j = 0
        while i < 4:
                i = i+1 

                res1 = s.read(10)
                decodedres1 = res1.decode()
                a = decodedres1.replace("\r\n" , "") 

                res2 = s.read(50) 
                decodedres2 = res2.decode()
                b = decodedres2.replace("\r\n" , "") 
                
                time = str(j)
                j = j + 5

                time.sleep(2)

                values = [time, a, b]
                print(values)
                Etable.insert('', 'end', values=values)

runningbtn = Button(root,command=run,text="Run")
runningbtn.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=13,pady=13)

Elist=['Time','Parameter1','Parameter2']
Etable=ttk.Treeview(root,column=Elist,show='headings',height=7)
for d in Elist:
    Etable.heading(d,text=d.title())
Etable.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=7,pady=7,columnspan=3)
```

I want the data I'm reading from the machine to be printed on the table every 2 seconds three times, and I thought I put the values for the table under the loop accordingly.

Instead, the data is getting accumulated then printed on the table all at once after six seconds. I've tried writing a separate loop for it, rearranging the placement of the values block, rewriting the loop and debugging it but the data keeps consistently outputting in one burst, any tips?

Comment: ok, pretty simple, don't use loops (while, for) in the same thread or process as `tkinter`, use [`.after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) "loops" instead (or start a new thread depending on how long each iteration takes)

Answer (score 0):

Tk requires events to be posted and handled regularly. When you move a mouse, the windowing system will generate a number of messages that are queued for event processing by Tk. If for any reason you fail to process these, your application will 'hang' and the user will see no updates to the UI. Most of this is handled by the `mainloop()` method which constantly waits for events and as soon as they are received handles them.

You have two problems above. You are presumably reading from a serial port (`s.read(10)`). This is a blocking call. Your thread will be suspended until 10 bytes become available on the serial port. While waiting for those bytes, no events can be processed because your application thread is suspended. To avoid this, either perform the reads on another thread and post the results to the main UI thread when they are ready or use a non-blocking read. eg test `s.inWaiting()` if this is a pyserial object and only read when all 10 bytes are available.

The second issue is do not use thread.sleep in Tkinter programs. Instead, break up the activity into two parts and call the second part using the Tkinter `after()` method. This queues an event to be handled at a certain interval that then runs your specified code. While this occurs all *other* events continue to be processed which leaves your application responsive.